# The difference between referring to a function and calling it ( this.myFunc vs this.myFunc() )

Tags: javascript

can someone please explain the difference between calling a method ( exp: this.myFunction()) and referring to a method (exp: this.myFunction )

Comment: You have already written down the difference in your question... One calls it the other refers to it.

Comment: this.myFunction can be assigned to variable(passed to func , reassigned etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @Cid's answer is absolutely correct, I thought about adding a few more details.

---

Functions are used to create *sub programs* inside a bigger program, which enables to write a repetitive task in a reusable way. To illustrate:

```
const increment = number => number + 1;
```

Here, `increment` is a binding to a (anonymous, e. g. *lambda*) function which takes a value and adds `1` to it.

**Yeah, fine. I already knew that**

What you might not know: In JavaScript, functions are "first-class objects". This means, one can pass a function around like any other variable, too. For example, it is possible to pass a function *as an argument to another function*. Consider `Array.prototype.map`.

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3];

numbers.map(increment); // -> [2, 3, 4]
```

To illustrate this in more detail, here is an implementation of a `map` function which doesn't rely on `Array.prototype.map` but mimics it:

```
const map = (funcReference, arrayOfXs) => {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfXs.length; i += 1) {
    result.push(funcReference(arrayOfXs[i]));
  }
  return result;
}
```

*Note: A fully equivalent `map` would need to pass the current index position as second, and the complete array as third parameter to `funcReference`.*

If we rewrite the `Array.prototype.map` example with it, the code becomes:

```
map(increment, numbers); // -> [2, 3, 4]
```

**OK, but that doesn't answer my question**

We are getting to it. Let's dismantle `map` to understand what's going on.

The first thing to note here, is that `map` takes a function reference as first argument (just like `Array.prototype.map` does), but that's just a *pointer* to the function to call/execute/apply, so the function *isn't called at that point*.

```
const map = (funcReference, arrayOfXs) =>
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//           points to increment
```

As an analogy, think of it as a recipe: If you pass a recipe to a cook, the meal won't be cooked as soon as you pass the recipe. Instead, the cook has to execute the instructions in it. A pointer is like passing the recipe, while a call executes the instructions.

The execution happens in this line:

```
result.push(funcReference(arrayOfXs[i]));
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//               execute increment
```

What does all of that mean in concrete? It means that the interpreter understands that *every time it sees `funcReference` inside `map`, it can replace it with `increment`*. It interprets the call `map(increment, numbers)` *as if* you'd written:

```
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
  result.push(increment(numbers[i]));
}
```

If we get rid of the `for` loop, it becomes:

```
const result = [];
result.push(increment(1));
result.push(increment(2));
result.push(increment(3));
```

Which we can further simplify:

```
const result = [];
result.push(1 + 1);
result.push(2 + 1);
result.push(3 + 1);
```

Hopefully, this clarifies things a bit.

---

For more information about functions, have a look at these MDN pages:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: thanks so much for the answer, it was really helpful.

Comment: @WaelFadhel No probs, glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is quite the same than the difference between a town (in your case calling a function) and a sign pointing to that town (referring to the function)

`myFunc()` executes the function. `myFunc` is a pointer to that function